# php download xml page and convert to utf-8

Tags: php, encoding

when I right-click on the xml page in the browser and save AS , and open it with Notepad++ it appears OK with the non english characters.
However if i write a script to save the page to my server, I have issues with character encoding. This is really a headache. Any help? thanks.

```
function download_page($path)
 {
//$path = htmlentities($path);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,1);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 280);
$retValue = curl_exec($ch);  
if (!$retValue){ //echo "erro curl";
        }                    

@curl_close($ch);
return $retValue;
 } 

 $file= download_page($url);
 $file = mb_convert_encoding($file, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
 $file = utf8_encode ($file);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code suggests that the result is encoded in UTF-8. First, are you sure it is true? And why do you need to convert it twice (first to `'HTML-ENTITIES`', than back to **UTF-8**)? If you just want to have html entities, use the [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) function.

Comment: i need the non english characters to appear (ě,ú,..)

Comment: They should appear, if you have a proper utf-8 file. I think you don't need the mb_convert_encoding line. But how do you write out the file? Do you use fwrite? If yes, check [this](http://hu.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php#73764). It's a little bit old post, but it might help.